# Can anyone explain this one line python code?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and new a clear explanation for a python one-line code.
What is the if condition actually doing?

here is the code:

```
def s(n, ar):
    result = 0   
    for i in range(n):
      if ar[i:].count(ar[i])%2==0:
        result +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for I in range(n):`
they are looping over n values
`if ar[I:].count(ar[I])%2==0`
Here he is checking the count of array value at index I, from that index to end of the list ar[I:] gives a subset list from that index to rest of list, and then he is dividing to check is it's even count or odd count, if it's even count, he is adding 1 to result

Comment: n=9,  ar = 10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20, according to your explanation, the output should be 1 but the output is 3.

Comment: The result would be 3 as you will get 3 even counts, i said it would add +1 to result